# Laravel Excel using with Ajax is not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I have search from that contain a lot of search elements, then in search result I have a print button that once again need to submit the search form with many other data to first find the records and then print it to excel. For this I have used Ajax for submitting the form and write with laravel excel, but now It is not working with `xlsx`, and has problem with `xls`. When `.xls`file is dowloaded It content is like this `ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`. Bellow is my code:

```
<script>
function generateReport(printType,printRange) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        })

        var url = '/auditLog/search/printReport';
        var params = $('#auditSearchForm').serialize()+'&printType=' + printType + '&printRange=' + printRange;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: params,
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                // check for a filename
                var filename = "";
                var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                }

                var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

                if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                    // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                } else {
                    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    if (filename) {
                        // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        // safari doesn't support this yet
                        if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                            window.location = downloadUrl;
                        } else {
                            a.href = downloadUrl;
                            a.download = filename;
                            document.body.appendChild(a);
                            a.click();
                        }
                    } else {
                        window.location = downloadUrl;
                    }

                    setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
                }

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

And my controller

```
public function generateReport()
{
    $result = $this->searchRequest->getDetails();
    //dd($result);
    //$user = Auth::user();
    Excel::create('foo', function($file) {
        $file->sheet('bar', function($sheet) {
            $sheet->setTitle('Hi');
        });
    })->download('xls');
}
```

For any help thanks.

Comment: You realise that response is the binary stream output for a BIFF-format Excel file? The trouble is that the Ajax response handler doesn't know what to do with it..... it's much easier to use a link for file downloads, rather than an ajax request, because then you can let the browser handle the response based on the response headers

Comment: @MarkBarker But with link how I can submit the form to not refresh the page?

Comment: Why not try it..... because the response headers for an Excel file are different to the response headers for an html response, the browser responds differently

Comment: @MarkBaker But I have another button on the form that submit the form for search method to search and show the result, so now how can I use another button to submit the same form in another function for print purpose?

Comment: I said a link (`<a href="...">`), not a button (though you can make a link look like a button if you want)

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

```
 $(function() {
        $('#your_div').on('click', '#print', function (e) {
            var reportRange = $('#report_range').val();
            downloadReport($(this).attr('printType'),reportRange);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });


    function downloadReport(printType,printRange){
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.responseType = 'blob';

        var header;
        var blob;
        var url = '/auditLog/search/printReport';
        var params = $('#auditSearchForm').serialize()+'&printType=' + printType + '&printRange=' + printRange;
        http.open("POST", url, true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                var filename = "";
                var disposition = http.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                }
                var type = http.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
                blob = new Blob([http.response], { type: type ,endings:'native'});
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    }
```

Comment: @paranoid Glad to helped you.